# Locality of function

Tags: caching, optimization, memory

Does this function have good locality with respect to array a? Justify your answer by calculating the average miss and hit rates if the array size is 10 times larger than the cache.

```
int sum_array_cols(int a[M][N])
{
    int i, j, sum = 0;
    for (j = 0; j < N; j++)
        for (i = 0; i < M; i++)
            sum += a[i][j];
    return sum;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably not.

In the inner loop you increment `i` what results in accessing memory locations separated by `N*sizeof(int)` bytes. The ratio of cache misses will depend on constant N and size of cache. The size (understood as `sizeof a`) will probably have no impact on cache effectiveness.

Moreover, the CPUs often do speculative prefetching of memory by tracing memory access pattern of your program. Therefore there might be little cache misses even though a small protion of cache is actually used. The exact answer must involve benchmarking on specific architecture.

To make thing more 'interesting', nowadays compiler will reorder the loop and improve locality automatically. Therefore I think that there is not enough data to provide a reliable answer to your question.